# Object not displaying

Tags: php

I was playing a bit with this code and did `echo $model->string;` Which should indeed not do anything because `$string` is protected.

However, why doesn't `echo $view->output();` do nothing as well? It should print 'asd' as a link. Another fun fact is that if I put this line of code above the other one it will work.

Why do I get a blank page, otherwise?

```
class Model
{
    protected $string;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->string = "asd";
    }

}


class Controller extends Model
{
    private $model;

    public function __construct($model){
        $this->model = $model;
    }
    public function get() {
        return $this->model->string;
    }
    public function clicked() {
        $this->model->string = "asadasdasdas";
    }
}
class View
{
    private $model;
    private $controller;

    public function __construct($controller,$model) {
        $this->controller = $controller;
        $this->model = $model;
    }


    public function output() {
        return '<p><a href="mvc.php?action=clicked">' . $this->controller->get() . '</a></p>';
    }
}

$model = new Model();
$controller = new Controller($model);
$view = new View($controller, $model);

if (isset($_GET['action']) && !empty($_GET['action'])) {
    $controller->{$_GET['action']}();
}

echo $model->string;
echo $view->output();


?>
```

Comment: when i run this i get a parse error and the code stop on line 50 (`echo $model->string;`) because its a protected var. If i comment out that line it works fine and produces the asd link

Comment: I know, but I don't get any error, it displays a blank page for me.

Comment: if you have `echo $model->string;` in your code, it is a Fatal Error. Thus everything ***after*** that won't run. Why you have a white page? Could be because of `error_reporting` or `display_error` settings in your php.ini indicate so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it is indeed protected.
$this->model->string (in function get()) can't get it either.

You also may not extend Controller from Model, as you insert Model as a parameter to the constructor of Controller.

What actuall would work is

```
public function get() {
    return $this->string;
}
```

Because Controller extends from Model and has his own $string. But I suppose this is not what you want, since it would defeat your

```
$model = new Model();
$controller = new Controller($model);
```

approach.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're protected is `protected` and not `private`.
You're assigning a protected value to a private value, another private value and displayed with a public function:

`public function() -> private $controller -> private $model -> protected $string;`

So because you're returning the previous class to the new ones, the 'permission-system` doesn't work like you would expect.

Better is to extend the classes, I guess you would get the result which would be expected.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example. But this is not really MVC what you are doing there..

However.. By letting your Controller extending your Model class, you have the methods of the Model class in the controller. But not the protected property.

```
<?php
class Model
{
    protected $string;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->string = "asd";
    }
    public function getString() {
        return $this->string;
    }


}


class Controller extends Model
{
}

class View
{
    private $controller;

    public function __construct($controller) {
        $this->controller = $controller;
    }


    public function output() {
        return '<p><a href="mvc.php?action=clicked">' . $this->controller->getString() . '</a></p>';
    }
}



$x = new Controller();
$y = new View($x);
echo $y->output();
```

Comment: What do you mean it's not MVC?

Comment: @GeorgeIrimiciuc I am referring to the MVC pattern.. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller which is not really implemented in the above example.

Comment: The view should not manipulate the controller. The controller should manipulate the view. And the Controller shouldn't extend the model. :) But you can play with it like that. The above example gives you an idea of how extending works and so on. I suggest reading up a little bit of simple mvc examples and general Object Oriented programming to cover the details about private/protected/public data.

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot. But Shouldn't the model have its variables non-public? Then how would the controller have access to them?

Answer (score -1):

you have declared the variable as `string` which is parsed by php as type of variable (like int,float).

if you will convert the string variable as $string2 it will work

Checkout this thing:

```
 class Model
{
    protected $string2;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->string2 = "asd";
    }

}


class Controller extends Model
{
    private $model;

    public function __construct($model){
        $this->model = $model;
    }
    public function get() {
        return $this->model->string2;
    }
    public function clicked() {
        $this->model->string2 = "asadasdasdas";
    }
}
class View
{
    private $model;
    private $controller;

    public function __construct($controller,$model) {
        $this->controller = $controller;
        $this->model = $model;
    }


    public function output() {
        return '<p><a href="mvc.php?action=clicked">' . $this->controller->get() . '</a></p>';
    }
}

$model = new Model();
$controller = new Controller($model);
$view = new View($controller, $model);

if (isset($_GET['action']) && !empty($_GET['action'])) {
    $controller->{$_GET['action']}();
}

//echo $model->string2;
echo $view->output();
```